# Extract digits from string with Python regular expression

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I ran the regular expression

```
re.findall(r"max .*([\d]+\.\d+)",m,re.I)
```

on the input

```
mps): 22.624001\r\nMax Phase Current Gain Error (Percent): 0.500000\r\nMax Phase Current Offset Error (Amps): 0.113120\r\nFan Control Timer (nS): 60000002048.000008\r\nPWM Dead Time (uS): 0.000004\r\n\r\n--------------------------AXIS_INSTANCE_3--------------------------\r\n\r\nPiccolo ServoIO Stats :\r\n\tTotal Missed Read Phase : 0\r\n\tTotal Missed Write Phase : 0\r\n\tTotal Read CRC Error : 0\r\n\tTotal Write CRC Error : 0\r\n\tTotal Invalid Seq. ID : 0\r\n\tTotal (General) Sequence Errors : 1\r\n\r\nOmap to Piccolo Read Packet :\r\nCommand/Fault Word : 0x0\r\nSequenceAndIncipSize : 0xc0\r\n\r\nOmap to Piccolo Read Packet :\r\nCommand/Fault Word : 0x0\r\nSequenceAndIncipSize : 0xc0\r\n\r\nPiccolo to Omap Read Packet :\r\nUPhase Current : 32779\r\nWPhase Current : 32776\r\nVbus : 0\r\n\r\nOmap to Piccolo Write Packet :\r\nUPhase Mod Idx : 0\r\nVPhase Mod Idx : 0\r\nWPhase Mod Idx : 0\r\n\r\nPiccolo to Omap Write Packet :\r\nStatus/Fault Word: 0x0\r\nSequenceAndIncipSize: 0x70\r\n\r\n\r\nPiccolo to Omap Low-Speed Data :\r\nPiccolo ADC Temp : 0.000000 degC\r\nPiccolo Igbt Temp : 23.618481 degC\r\n\r\nPower Interface Scaling:\r\nPhase Current Feedback Offset Counts: 32767.000000\r\nPhase Current Feedback Gain Scaling: -0.002142\r\nDC Bus Voltage Feedback Offset Counts: 0.000000\r\nDC Bus Voltage Feedback Gain Scaling: 0.013757\r\nMax Phase Current (Amps): 609.198303\r\nPhase Current Gain Error Measurement Point (Amps): 22.624001\r\nMax Phase Current Gain Error (Percent): 0.500000\r\nMax Phase Current Offset Error (Amps): 0.113120\r\nFan Cont
```

which does not give me the correct result.  It skips two or more digits. What's wrong?

Comment: What *is* the correct result?  Show us what you've tried in a deeper sense: not just the regular expression, but why you thought it would work, the output you get, and the output you expected.  Otherwise, we can't really help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm ***guessing*** that you want to use a [lazy match on the dot-match-all](https://regex101.com/r/bP0wM8/2).

```
max .*?(\d+\.\d+)
```

By default, most regular expressions are greedy (i.e. they try to match as much as possible, from left to right). When you say `max .*`, it matches `Max` and then everything to the very end of the string. Then your code "backtracked" until it found the last instance of `\d+\.\d+`. Adding the `?` after a quantifier (`*`, `+`, etc.) means that it stops matching as soon as the next sequence (in this case, the digits) is found.

You'll also notice that I removed the unnecessary character class around the first `\d`.

---

Sometimes, if you can, I'd recommend avoiding lazy repetition. It seems like all of your input is formatted similarly -- "Max [field] ([unit]): [value]" -- meaning we can be [more specific with the expression](https://regex101.com/r/bP0wM8/3):

```
(Max [^:]+): ([\d.]+)
```

I, personally, would much rather see the latter regex in my (or an employee's) code. It has less room for unintended consequences, has better performance, and is more obvious as to what you want it to match.

Comment: Input = 'bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=255\r\n\r\nPing statistics for 192.168.1.1:\r\n    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),\r\nApproximate round trip times in milli-seconds:\r\n    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 1ms\r\n'

For above string I used
{  re.findall(r"Pack[^\(]+(\d)",t,re.I)  } regex. but it is not working too. i need  [4,4,0] as output. Can u pls explain me what am i doing wrong in my regex?

Comment: @OO7 you're just capturing one single digit -- how'd you expect it to get all 3 digits? Use something like [`Packets: [^=]+= (\d), [^=]+= (\d), [^=]+= (\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/uU1gW7/1) instead.

Comment: Hey Sam, You are awesome. Thanks for your support. But i need an output as list Like [4,4,0] instead of [('4', '4', '0')]. can we do that?

Comment: Use [`list(re.search(r'...', Input).groups())`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead of [`re.findall(r'...', Input)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search).

Comment: list(re.search(r"Packets: [^=]+= (\d), [^=]+= (\d), [^=]+= (\d)",t,re.I).group()) is not working . its give o/p like ['P', 'a', 'c', 'k', 'e', 't', 's', ':', ' ', 'S', 'e', 'n', 't', ' ', '=', ' ', '4', ',', ' ', 'R', 'e', 'c', 'e', 'i', 'v', 'e', 'd', ' ', '=', ' ', '4', ',', ' ', 'L', 'o', 's', 't', ' ', '=', ' ', '0']

Comment: `.groups()` not `.group()`